# How to style Symfony2 form prototype

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have a collection of form in Symfony2. I need to style those forms with some specific div structure, something like this:

```
<div class="block" style="clear: both;">
  {{ form_row(form.name) }}
  {{ form_row(form.address) }}
</div>
<div class="block">
  {{ form_row(form.website) }}
  {{ form_row(form.email) }}
</div>
<div>
 <div>
   {{ form_row(form.text1) }}
 </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, the structure is not regular and I don't have an idea how to style it in the {% for row in rows %} loop in {% block collection_widget %}. Any ideas how I can style/build form prototype so the form added with javascript will look exact as I want?

Comment: Is the HTML you've posted the contents of your form prototype that you wish to have?

Comment: More or less but yes. This is just part of the code I want to have in prototype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the best way is to have separate twig template for the form and then pass the form/prototype into that like..

<kbd>_form.html.twig</kbd>

```
<div class="block" style="clear: both;">
    {{ form_row(form.name) }}
    {{ form_row(form.address) }}
</div>
<div class="block">
    {{ form_row(form.website) }}
    {{ form_row(form.email) }}
</div>
<div>
    <div>
        {{ form_row(form.text1) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

<kbd>update.html.twig</kbd>

```
<ul data-prototype="{{ include('_form.html.twig', 
                                {'form': form.items.vars.prototype })|e }}">
    {% for item in form.items %}
        <li>{{ include('_form.html.twig', {'form': item }) }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This will allow you to pass in your form items prototype into the same template that you are using for your actual form items, meaning that you only have to update one template when things change.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a simple for loop in twig, without extending the  {% block collection_widget %}:

```
{% for counter in form.MyCollection %}
<div class="block" style="clear: both;">
  {{ form_row(form.MyCollection[loop.index0].name) }}
  {{ form_row(form.MyCollection[loop.index0].address) }}
</div>
<div class="block">
  {{ form_row(form.MyCollection[loop.index0].website) }}
  {{ form_row(form.MyCollection[loop.index0].email) }}
</div>
<div>
 <div>
   {{ form_row(form.MyCollection[loop.index0].text1) }}
 </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Why loop.index[0]? Also, where I should put this code?

Comment: ok, I tried it and understand it. No more explanantion needed :)